# What is the role of the (if block) inside the function in the code below?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, c++11, linear-interpolation

This is an interpolation search which I found in an YouTube video but without sound. I have understood most of the part in the code but why do I need to use the if(key == arr[low])?

```
if (key == arr[low]){

    return low ;

} else {

    return -1;

}
```

The whole program is down below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int z = 0;

int interpolation(int arr[], int left, int right, int key){

    int low = left;
    int high = right - 1;
    int mid;

    while (arr[high] != arr[low] && key >= arr[low] && key <= arr[high]) {

        mid = low + ( (key - arr[low]) * (high - low) / (arr[high] - arr[low]) );

        if (key > arr[mid]){

            low = mid + 1;

        } else if (key < arr[mid]){

            high = mid - 1;

        } else{

            return mid;

        }

    }

    if (key == arr[low]){

        return low ;

    } else {

        return -1;

    }

}

int main()
{

    int L[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610};
    //int L[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int left = 0;
    int right = sizeof(L) / sizeof(L[0]);

    int key = 6;

    int x;
    if((x = interpolation(L, left, right, key)) == -1 ){

        cout << "Key doesn't exist"<< endl;

    } else {

        cout << "The position of Key is " << x << endl;

    }

return 0; }
```

Without this part, some of the index does not work. However, isn't the else inside the while loop covering the whole thing?

```
else{

     return mid;

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Could be there to handle the case of an array consisting of exactly one element. In this case, the main `while` loop doesn't run at all.

Answer (score 0):

When the `while` loop finishes, one or more of the conditions below are true:

1. `arr[high] == arr[low]`, or
2. `key < arr[low]`, or
3. `key > arr[high]`

This is an application of [DeMorgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to `while`'s continuation condition.

If only conditions 2 or 3 are true, the `key` is not found, so the algorithm returns `-1`. If condition 1 is true, you found a "flat" stretch between `high` and `low`. In this case, the algorithm should return any index between `low` and `high` if `arr[low]` or `arr[high]` match `key`; if the numbers from the flat stretch do not match the `key`, return -1.

> isn't the else inside the while loop covering the whole thing?

You may not get to that part in the loop, if you find a flat stretch before hitting the spot with the search key. You need this condition, because gradient search is not possible when the function runs flat.